# Update member in class using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, updates

I have a class with 5 members.
like that:

```
class Demo
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string color;
    public int 4th_member;
    public int 5th_member;
}
```

I have list of this class.

for the `4th_member`, and `5th_member`, I have 2 list of dictionary with int key and int value. (one for 4th, and the second for 5th)

I want to update these members, according to the dictionary.
like, if dictionary's key = id, then update `4th_member` to be value of Dictionary.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: why do you insist on using linq, when the acronym stands for a query *language* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the below code its working fine.

Hope this will solve your problem if I have understood your question properly

```
var demo = demoTest.Select(s =>
           {
            s.Fourthth_member = dic.GetValueFromDictonary(s.Fourthth_member);
            s.Fifthth_member = dic1.GetValueFromDictonary(s.Fifthth_member);
            return s;
          }).ToList();

//Extension method
public static class extMethod
{
  public static int GetValueFromDictonary(this Dictionary<int, int> dic, int key)
    {
        int value = 0;

        dic.TryGetValue(key, out value);

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: beautiful and elegant way! Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't understand who give you -1.

Comment: @Sathish - Just so you know, in the first linq option you loose the `o(1)` that you have when accessing a dictionary by key so your second way is better

Answer (score 1):

linq is not used for updating data but for queries. This is a possible solution:

```
foreach(var demo in demoList)
{
    if(dictionaries[0].ContainsKey(demo.id))
    {
        demo.member4 = dictionaries[0][demo.id];
    }

    if (dictionaries[1].ContainsKey(demo.id))
    {
        demo.member5 = dictionaries[1][demo.id];
    }
}
```

Or with the `TryGetValue`

```
foreach(var demo in demoList)
{
    int value;
    if(dictionaries[0].TryGetValue(demo.id, out value))
    {
        demo.member4 = value;
    }

    if (dictionaries[1].TryGetValue(demo.id, out value))
    {
        demo.member5 = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should think about using `.TryGetValue` instead of doing `.ContainsKey` and `[]`. it may not be relevant in this very scenario, but in multithreaded scenarios your approach will fail with eg concurrent dictionaries (where `.TryGetValue` is implemented as an *atomic* operation)

Comment: Agree with what you say - valuable comment. Just wanted to keep it closer to the way the question is written

Comment: @prog_prog - Does this help you with your question?

Comment: thanks for incorporating my suggestion, but you can reuse `value` instead of going for another read-access with `[]` :)

Comment: I'm change a little your solution, but its work. thank.

Comment: I prefer finally the second way (of Sathish) because its shorter.